# Any way to register in Google Cloud Platform and in Microsoft Azure for free trial (no credit card required)?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform

Any way to register in Google Cloud Platform and in Microsoft Azure for free trial (no credit card required)?
He asks me for a credit card to start the test, but I do not have a credit card (I do not even have money in my country).
What is the other way to register with Google Cloud Platform and Microsoft Azure without a credit card?
Greetings. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to get a free trial on GCP or Azure without a credit card. Note that although they asked for a credit card you wont have any charge until you explicitly upgrade your account [1] [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions
[2] https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/